# Incompleteness of FindInstance

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

I've been playing around with `Resolve` and `FindInstance`.  I know that `Resolve` should always be decidable when the domain is `Reals` by [Tarski's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TarskisTheorem.html), but I don't know about `FindInstance`.  I tried using `FindInstance` to find a lower bound on the absolute value of a real number, but it didn't succeed.

```
(* First-order logic characterization of absolute value. a = |x|. *)
MyAbs[x_, a_] := (x > 0 \[Implies] a == x) ∧ (x <= 0 \[Implies] a == -x)

(* Returns True, so yes there is a lower bound. *)
Resolve[Exists[l, ForAll[{x, a}, (MyAbs[x, a]) \[Implies] a >= l]], Reals]

(* Returns True, so yes 0 is a lower bound. *)
Resolve[ForAll[{x, a}, (MyAbs[x, a]) \[Implies] a >= 0], Reals]

(* Returns {}, so Mathematica can't find a specific lower bound. *)
FindInstance[ForAll[{x, a}, (MyAbs[x, a]) \[Implies] a >= l], {l}, Reals]

(* Using the standard Abs also returns {} *)
FindInstance[ForAll[x, Abs[x] >= l], {l}, Reals]
```

Why is `FindInstance` not returning `{{l -> 0}}`?

Comment: It does return `{{l -> 0}}` for me. I think this is due to a version difference. Mine is 8.0.4. There have been several such errors and differences between 8.0.0 and 8.0.4 (way too many for a minor revision)

Comment: @R.M Post that as an answer. There is not going to be a better one.

Answer (score 1):

[rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5) answered in [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8837/incompleteness-of-findinstance#comment25400_8837) that

> It does return `{{l -> 0}}` for me. I think this is due to a version difference. Mine is 8.0.4. There have been several such errors and differences between 8.0.0 and 8.0.4 (way too many for a minor revision).